# Meaning of 差 in 现在差一刻九点?

Tags: meaning

I have difficulties understanding sentence.
What is meaning of 差 in the following sentence?

> 我看一下，现在差一刻九点。

Comment: I would normally say 九点差一刻. Regional difference maybe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It literally means `differ`. `差一刻九点` means `a quarter to nine`. `差` in the phrase `差一点` and `差几块钱/几个月` means the same, that is, adding the amount missed will turn the current situation into the target situation (could be better or worse).

Comment: I see. It shows how lack something to target. Xiexie

Comment: @BorisIvanov It means `differ`, not necessarily `lack`. However in the examples in this answer you can safely interpret it as `lack`.

Comment: When u say differ it means it can be over target, but in this example its not reaching it. Can you use it if u gave more money?(差几块钱)

Comment: I guess it's always lack regarding payment, because you are paying from 0 up to the required amount... but if your target is towards a smaller value, such as running time in sports, it is not _lack_ numerically. For instance, 差0.1秒就能进决赛了, means one takes 0.1 second longer than the cutting line to be qualified for the final round.

Answer (score 0):

I would interpret 差 as short of/lack, as in "we are 15 minutes short from reaching 9 o'clock."